# Java: CoreAnimation: 911 by 34488 image is too large for software renderer, ignoring

Tags: java, user-interface, resize, rsa

Why does Java freezes and throws the "**CoreAnimation: 911 by 34488 image is too large for software renderer, ignoring**" error, when I try to resize the window by mouse?

This is a primitive RSA encryption-decryption class, with an even more primitive UI.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.security.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class rsa {
    private final static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    private static BigInteger privateKey;
    private static BigInteger publicKey;
    private static BigInteger modulus;

    rsa(int N) {
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(N / 2, random);
        BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(N / 2, random);
        BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))).multiply(q.subtract(new BigInteger("1")));

        modulus = p.multiply(q);
        publicKey = new BigInteger("65537");
        privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(phi);
    }

    BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger message) {
        return message.modPow(publicKey, modulus);
    }

    BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger encrypted) {
        return encrypted.modPow(privateKey, modulus);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int N = Integer.parseInt("2048");
        rsa key = new rsa(N);

        String tocode = "Even though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil, for you are with me; your rod and your staff, they comfort me.";

        BigInteger intcode = new BigInteger(tocode.getBytes());
        BigInteger encrypt = key.encrypt(intcode);
        BigInteger decrypt = key.decrypt(encrypt);

        Iterator<String> parcelIt = parcel(intcode, 10).iterator();

        gui(tocode, intcode, encrypt, decrypt, N, parcelIt);
    }

    public static List<String> parcel(BigInteger inputInteger, int size) {
        String inputString = inputInteger.toString();
        List<String> parcelled = new ArrayList<String>();
        parcelled.add(Arrays.toString(inputString.split("(?<=\\G.{" + size + "})")));
        return parcelled;
    }

    public static void gui(String tocode, BigInteger intcode, BigInteger encrypt, BigInteger decrypt, int N, Iterator<String> parcelIt) {
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(0, 0);
        textarea.setLineWrap(true);
        textarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 9);
        textarea.setFont(font);
        textarea.setForeground(new Color(0x88, 0x88, 0xff));
        textarea.setBackground(new Color(0x30, 0x30, 0x30));

        textarea.append("Modulus:\n" + modulus + "\n\n");
        textarea.append("Public key:\n" + publicKey + "\n\n");
        textarea.append("Private key:\n" + privateKey + "\n\n");
        textarea.append("Message in String:\n" + tocode + "\n\n");
        textarea.append("Message in BigInteger:\n" + intcode + "\n\n");

        textarea.append("Parcels: (for test only)\n");
        while (parcelIt.hasNext()) {
            String value = (String) parcelIt.next();
            textarea.append(value + ", ");
        }

        textarea.append("\n\nEncrpyted message:\n" + encrypt + "\n\n\n\n");
        textarea.append("Decrypted in BigInteger:\n" + decrypt + "\n\n");
        textarea.append("Decrypted in String:\n" + new String(decrypt.toByteArray()) + "\n\n");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RSA-" + N);
        frame.add(textarea);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        Dimension windowSize = frame.getSize();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int windowX = Math.max(0, (screenSize.width  - windowSize.width ) / 2);
        int windowY = Math.max(0, (screenSize.height - windowSize.height) / 2);
        frame.setLocation(windowX, windowY);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Stack Trace:**

```
2013-03-29 00:59:42.707 java[38707:707] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface
    at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:298)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:98)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:324)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:234)
2013-03-29 00:59:42.709 java[38707:707] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cdd7b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8c81b3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce6bf49 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   JavaNativeFoundation                0x0000000124065539 JNFCallVoidMethod + 209
    4   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000124ef4f77 -[AWTWindow _deliverMoveResizeEvent] + 310
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cd89eda _CFXNotificationPost + 2554
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff91d48e26 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8eb0a4ce -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] + 2322
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f253a69 -[NSWindow(NSWindowResizing) _resizeWithEvent:] + 1587
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f059de9 -[NSTitledFrame mouseDown:] + 189
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f0577fe -[NSThemeFrame mouseDown:] + 281
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebc053e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
    12  liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000124ef2e33 -[AWTWindow_Normal sendEvent:] + 86
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebbc674 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
    14  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000012481cad1 -[NSApplicationAWT sendEvent:] + 179
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ead224a -[NSApplication run] + 636
    16  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000012481c9b9 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
    17  liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000124ee4a5a -[AWTStarter starter:] + 1591
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff91d92d3a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cd56b31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cd56455 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cd797f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cd790e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
    23  java                                0x000000010b5264bc CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
    24  java                                0x000000010b520cac JLI_Launch + 1952
    25  java                                0x000000010b526819 main + 101
    26  java                                0x000000010b520504 start + 52
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000005 0x0 + 5
)
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace (if one is available).

Comment: I edited the question, it is now there.

Comment: Well, your code works just fine on my Windows 7 machine running Java 7. The window resizes smoothly and there's no particular load on the system. The stack trace shows that your app ran out of memory, probably while trying to double-buffer the app's window. The image dimensions are very strange; it suggests stack or memory corruption somewhere. Have you tried running your code on another machine (perhaps with a different Java version)?

Comment: what version of java (type java -version) and maybe more mem but i dont see why the 2d packages are being accessed. ran on my system with default memory, java 7 ad 6 (update 32)